# can you spot the error in this xpath

Tags: xpath

I'm a little new to xpath and I was wondering if you anyone can help me understand what's wrong with the following xpath query. The server is telling me I have an "invalid predicate"

Here's the xpath:

```
xpath("div[span[@class='paragraphnumber]/text()='$next_pn']/@id")
```

I want this to find the @id of the div which contains within it a span element with the @class of "paragraphnumber" and the text which equals the number contained in the variable $next_pn. The div would look something like this:

```
<div id="pl8ddjkdj"><span class="paragraphnumber">3</span>lor ipsum etc etc</div>
```

Basically, I'm starting with the number I want to be able to find the unique id of this div.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have missed a single quote ( `'` ) after the name of the class `paragraphnumber`

Comment: Everyone makes such mistakes, don't worry (: Is this fixed the problem? I could add it as answer it does.

Comment: Yes, it works now - it appears that everything else in the line was right. Please add it as the proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have just missed a single quote (`'`) after the name of the class `paragraphnumber`.

This:

```
xpath("div[span[@class='paragraphnumber]/text()='$next_pn']/@id")
```

should be

```
//                                     v
xpath("div[span[@class='paragraphnumber']/text()='$next_pn']/@id")
```